# Can Notebooks Inherit Options through Stylesheets?

Tags: stylesheet, input-alias

**Motivation:** Is there some way to bundle notebook-level options such as `InputAliases` into a stylesheet, so that notebooks styled with it inherit those options?

From quickly testing this, it seems not to be possible, and that you always have to run the command `SetOptions[nb, ...]` to set any Options for a Notebook.

*But maybe there's a workaround that I'm missing?*

Comment: If you're looking for this sort of thing, I suggest looking in `"Core.nb"` at how features  are implemented

Answer (score 1):

Yes, apply them to a style named "Notebook".

**Warning**:  This will override the default InputAliases created by the FE on startup, so you will lose InputAliases such \intt that are tied to that option, unless you extract and embedded into the stylesheet as well.  Which means you'll need to periodically update it if you want to keep getting the new aliases.

Finding a way to merge theme is somewhere on our to do list.

Comment: A richer inheritance mechanism w/r/t stylesheets (e.g. inheriting from multiple sheets) is something I've often wanted. I can imagine more flexible inheritance would help with this too.

Comment: About keeping them up to date, maybe something along `InputAliases -> {ParentList, customaliases__}` would work, can't test now.

Comment: @Kuba, I believe it does.